# Why is density considered constant over a length $dz$ but not pressure?

Tags: pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, calculus, density

When deriving the formula for hydrostatic equilibrium in the atmosphere, one usually considers a slab of air at altitude $z$, of thickness $dz$ and cross section $A$, and then writes $$A(P(z)-P(z+dz)) = - gA\rho(z)dz$$ (equilibrium condition). This expresses that the difference in pressure forces opposes the weight of the slab.

In some cases, like an isothermal atmosphere of ideal gas, $P$ and $\rho$ are proportional to each other, and thus have the same variations. What is then the justification for the asymmetrical treatment of $\rho$ and $P$, namely why is density considered constant and equal to $\rho(z)$ over $dz$ while variations of pressure are considered ?

Comment: I agree with the poster.  Density should be expressed as $\rho(P)$ rather than $\rho(z)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might well account for the density $\rho$ varying
over the distance $dz$. You can do this by using the average density
$\frac{\rho(z)+\rho(z+dz)}{2}$ instead of simply $\rho(z)$
in the equilibrium condition.
Then you would get
$$A(P(z)-P(z+dz)) = - gA\frac{\rho(z)+\rho(z+dz)}{2}dz.$$

But when you now divide by $A\ dz$ and do the limit $dz\to 0$,
then you will get the same differential equation
$$-\frac{dP(z)}{dz} = - g\rho(z)$$
as before with the simple $\rho(z)$ approach.
So there is no need to bother with this.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing would be gained by considering the variation in density rather than its average value over the differential region.

Since the parameter variation is suitably linear over the infinitesimal height, the average density $\rho(z)$ is essentially independent of the spatial gradient of the density. So we ignore the slope $d\rho(z)/dz$. But it’s precisely the spatial gradient $dP(z)/dz$ of the pressure that we seek to model, so we must incorporate that difference $P(z+dz)-P(z)$ rather than looking only at an average.

(And as for taking the density average at one end of the differential element rather than at the middle, the difference is infinitesimal.)